# Virtualenv Installation via pip & conda on Mac

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, conda

I want to install virtualenv on macOS.

I tried

**pip install virtualenv**

which resulted in the below

**Collecting virtualenv
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590) - skipping**

Decided to use conda instead

**conda install virtualenv**

which gave me

**CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/repodata.json.bz2
Elapsed: None**

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
SSLError(SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),),)

Please help with alternative suggestion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi

Comment: Do not use `virtualenv` with conda. Use conda environments instead.